# Example to use boost::weak_ptr to break cyclic dependencies

Tags: boost

I have seen one of the usages of `boost::weak_ptr` is to break cyclic dependencies. Can someone give me a simple concrete example to illustrate this feature?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In simple terms:

```
{  // Enter scope

  shared_ptr<A> my_a(new A);
  shared_ptr<B> my_b(new B);

  my_a->remember_this_b( my_b );  // Stores a copy of a smart pointer
  my_b->remember_this_a( my_a );  // Stores a copy of a smart pointer

} // Leave scope.  my_a and my_b are destroyed.
```

If both these functions stored a `shared_ptr`, **the objects would never be deleted**, because neither `shared_ptr` would reach a reference count of zero.

However, if either one used a `weak_ptr`, the object pointed to by the `weak_ptr` would be destroyed when leaving the scope.  And that would in turn destroy the last `shared_ptr` to the other object.